# Amazon SNS Notifications on S3 objects

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sns

We would like to publish a message to SNS Topic subscribers, and the notification can happen in different forms. One is if a new object is placed there will be one notification and if a object is updated then there will be another notification and the same way if an object deleted.

Example:
SNS Topic: MyTopic
S3 Path: s3://mybucket/myfolder1/myfolder2/myfolder3/

Task:
1. So if I add a file1 to this S3 path, then a notifications should be sent out to all subscribers of MyTopic.
2. If file1 has updated, then a notification should be sent out
3. If file1 has deleted, then a notification should be sent out.

Is there a IAM policy we can define that matches to all these criteria.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get a specific notification when an object is updated (vs. created). When you are either creating an object or updating it (in fact, the right word would be "replacing"), you're going to use the same [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html). [SNS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types) are consistent with this affirmation and only have policies for object creation.

Comment: Ok, My idea is I want to implement some listeners for SNS Notifications that I receive. Is there a way for this. Can we implement listeners form "email-json" protocol that SNS supports.